# Qt application gray on OpenBox when launched from autostart.sh

Tags: openbox

I have a Qt application, I have added it to `~/.config/openbox/autostart.sh` like this:

```
(sleep 5 && /home/user/UI/UI) &
```

When I start Openbox from terminal, the Qt application opens as a unusable gray box.
If I launch xterm on Openbox and then manually start the Qt application, it works fine. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is this a java app?

Comment: No it's not. It's just a simple Qt app with dependencies to Qt libraries only.

Comment: Qt is a graphical toolkit that you use to create windows and widgets and stuff, but not a programming language. Any idea what language the program is written in?

Comment: C++, compiled on the same system. Even with Hello World this problem occurs.

Answer (score 0):

In such a situation,  it can be helpful to trace program execution. Two tools that can be used for this are strace and gdb:

1. Use strace to log system calls, using `-o file` to write the log to a file. This will show you when the program hangs while executing a system call
2. Use gdb to attach to the running process (via `-p pid`), and check the stack trace of all threads

This might give an idea of why the process hangs.